# Demonstrative pronoun: does it have to match the subject?

Tags: grammar, noun, gender, declension, inflection

I'm a little confused about German grammar, the demonstratives to be specific (*this, that, these, those*). Does the demonstrative pronoun have to match the subject being described?

Example:
Would *This woman* be *Diese Frau*?

Comment: Can be found with a Google search.  There is no particular question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite straightforward:

- this = dieser/diese/dieses
- that = jener/jene/jenes
- these = diese
- those = jene

So you are correct, "this woman" is "diese Frau".